# php/mysql - bad concurrency issue to solve

Tags: php, mysql, concurrency

**The variables:**

1) Table named doc_types, that has many type of documents that a user wants in it's system.

- Fields: id_doc_type as int(14) AUTOINCREMENT, name as varchar(25)

2) Table named documents, that has all the documents the user creates.

- Fields: id_document as int(14) AUTOINCREMENT, id_doc_type as int(14), doc_number as int(14), etc...

3) Table named secuence, that is a hack for the concurrency problem I'm still having.

- Fields: id_secuence as int(14) AUTOINCREMENT, ref as as int(14)

**The problem:**

The server has a load of more or less 1200 queries per second, with more than 100 unique users in a concurrent scheme at peak times. Each user generates several documents types and each one must have it's unique number by document type.
So long, I still can't have it fixed.

**My currrent solution:**
2 functions:

1) Called for generating the next number using an AUTOINCREMENT to ensure its result

```
function generate_secuence($last_number)
    {
        // get the last id generated in the secuence table
        $sql="select max(id_secuence) as last_secuence from secuence";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);
        $row=mysql_fecth_object($result);
        $last_secuence=$row->last_secuence;

        // insert a decoy in order to generate the unique autoincrement number
        $sql="insert into secuence (ref) values ('$last_number')";
        mysql_query($sql);
        $new_secuence=mysql_insert_id();

        // calculate the next number in a way that we get hold of the autoincrement regardless of the user timing
        $next_number=$last_number - $last_secuence + $new_secuence;
        return($next_number);
    }
```

2) Called when each document is been saved if it doesn't have a number already.

```
function get_next_doc_number($doc_type)
    {
        // get the last number of the document type the user is saving
        $sql="select max(doc_number) as last_num from documents where id_doc_type='$doc_type'";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);
        $row=mysql_fecth_object($result);
        $last_number=$row->last_num;

        // call the function 
        $next_number=generate_secuence($last_number);   
        return($next_number);
    }
```

My question:
Where is it that my solution is failing to get a hold on the problem and how should I fix it?

Comment: You should probably use a transaction for the whole docid-generation chain. Most importantly the INSERT INTO sequence would already generate a unique autoincrement id. Querying the table beforehand for the MAX(id_sequence) and then substracting that is pointless, and the source of its flakyness. -- Also please turn your question title into a concise summary, not a tag list.